# Calling Exe from another application

Tags: c#, assemblies, exe

I have a complete command line application in c# which has different modules and depends on multiple dlls etc.

Now, i want to call that CLI app with an another UI app. But the issue is that the Thread part of the CLI applicaiton is not working and the control just jumps to the end. So, is there any way I can handle this scenario?

For example: I have app CLI.exe which i want to call so i have written following code:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = CLI.exe;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Now this calls the app i want to call. The following code is there in my app CLI.exe

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Start app {0}", args);
       do
       {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
       } while (model.Exited == false);
System.Console.WriteLine("Finish app");
```

Now, in between the do while loop, I do a lot pf processing while the model.exit don't get false.
But it starts the app, writes the Start app message and just after that it writes the Finish app and the processing in between never happened.

model.Exit also went true without processing.

Also, if I run the CLI.exe with the batch command or run the CLI.exe on cmd it runs perfectly.

So, any idea as how to manage this?

Comment: what is model.exited and did u check why it became True

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the application you're calling. Perhaps some dependency on the standard input? How do you initialize `model.Exited`? How do you set it inside the loop?

Comment: model.exited have called another exe abc.exe in multiple threads and when the threads finishes, it sets the model.exited true.
It seems like the threads of that abc.exe never ran and i dont know why becasue in standalone mode and in batch command way it worked well.

Comment: What about configuration? Is your CLI.exe app configured correctly when you execute it from the UI app?

Comment: yes, the configuration is good as the control is entering with the correct entry point until the thread part comes in do while loop.

Answer (score 0):

`proc.WaitForExit();` freezes your process until child process is finished. Remove that and handle process exit in another way, for example, using events:

```
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
proc.Exited += OnExit;
```

Comment: thanks, but it dont solve the issue as i have already tried it. The issue might be that any thread is not working inside the CLI.exe.

Comment: Oh all right I thought that's the same app code. You definitely should describe what you do with model, otherwise there can be hundred of reasons. Btw, does cli.exe use input?

Comment: yeah, CLI is taking the arguments as a file and some other params. The model again use that file and and the parameters and send to another exe in multiple threads and each thread then returns xml and that xml is then processed and the output parameters then create another xml with the result. So,the CLI,exe is a huge application with multiple modules and many thread models inside that and have dependency on over 30-40 dlls and those dlls have further dependency on some system dlls and third party dlls.